# Is "shrubble" a well-defined word?

Tags: meaning, spelling-pronunciations

Is "shrubble" a well-defined word? I thought it means low lying brush and dirt.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by “is it a word”? It looks like a blend of the words “shrub” and “rubble”. I can easily imagine that “shrubble” might be used as jargon by some particular group of speakers that find it useful to have such a word, but as far as I know it is not in common use. Can you give a more detailed description of how you encountered this word?

Comment: I cannot remember where I first encountered it, but I always thought it was a well-defined word. E.g. He wandered into the shrubble. @sumelic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Shrubble" n. A little sprout or spray.
>
> 1674 N. Fairfax Treat. Bulk & Selvedge 128
>
> The seed heaves up from a sprouting or **shrubble** to the scantling of height..that nature has cut out for it.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/178963?redirectedFrom=shrubble#eid)

It looks to me as though 'shrubble' is the diminutive of 'shrub'.

I've learned a new word, today.